# Datavisualization datetime axis quarterly format

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, format, mschart

I am using the .NET datavisualization library to create some charts. The data is all time series based (ie, the x-axis is dates).

I know that I can use custom date and time format strings to format the x-axis labels (formatting from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), via the

```
AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy"
```

command.

But what if I wanted to format the labels via a custom function that isn't provided in the .NET library?

To be more specific, is it possible to format the x-axis labels using the Quarter of the date? In other words:

- Jan-Mar: Q1
- Apr-Jun: Q2
- Jul-Sep: Q3
- Oct-Dec: Q4

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own function and return custom labels and assign them to data point individually

Eg:-

```
string lblText = CustomLabelFunction(Chart1.Series["Default"].Points[0]);
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points[0].AxisLabel = lblText;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Its too bad it has to be so cumbersome, but at least this works.

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone further, I prefer to use a List and bind the list to the chart.

```
List<string> xValues = new List<string>() { 
"Jan-Mar: Q1", "Apr-Jun: Q2", "Jul-Sep: Q3", "Oct-Dec: Q4" }; 

List<int> yValues = new List<int>() { 2, 8, 4, 21};

// Assign the data to the chart
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
```

For information, this would get overridden:

```
Chart1.Series["Default"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
```